# How to override Quarkus Resteasy urls during testing?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

When doing integration tests with Quarkus Restclient / RESTEasy we would want to override the url and port during runtime.
The reason for this is that if we build multiple modules in parallel we need to use random ports as otherwise we will get port clashes or alternatively we need to very carefully coordinate which module uses which ports.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing, and specificaly if setting `quarkus.http.test-port=0`, solves  your problem

Comment: Thanks, but that only solves the issue with the applications http port. We need to override the Restclients urls preferably during runtime. The other option is that we set specific ports for each service when running tests which is doable but not as elegant